# I use vim for notetaking. Can I fold/filter to relevant notes by tag?

Tags: tags

I use vim for notetaking. I use a simple format like this:

```
Friday, August 27, 2021 01:00 pm / tech leadership
What should our top priorities be? Monthly priority review.
Can we budget for continual improvement?
Quarterly backlog review with entire team

Monday, August 30, 2021 10:14 am / project a
tues go live with v1.12
bulk create sites, populate them
standups etc.?
decom project?

Monday, August 30, 2021 02:34 pm / project b
etc.
```

Is there a way (ideally using vanilla vim) to @tag each entry such that I can filter to view only notes relevant to a particular topic or project? I am involved in so many efforts and meetings that search is often too slow for me. Some kind of folding or filtering would be ideal.

Comment: you may need to define a customer fold-expression. Or use fold-markers around each note.

Comment: I watched this [video](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/) on your suggestion but it seems custom folds only support levels, not tags. I didn't see anything to suggest that folding could take a parameter (i.e., fold everything except blocks with tag X).

Comment: `:vimgrep /@tag/ %` is nice, assuming it's all in one file. If it's a directory tree, probably `:grep … @tag …`

Comment: whatever your tag is, you can define it in a syntax file (together with syntax folding) and have the surrounding paragraph being folded. Or again as a fold-expression, each paragraph within a tag can be folded. Or, if you separate your notes by more than a single empty line, you could use this: `:g/@tag/'{,'}fold`